# Why Lambda doesn't allow contra-variance?

Tags: c#, lambda, contravariance

I have the following classes defined.

```
 public class Animal { }
 public class Mammal : Animal { }
```

Why is the following lambda statement illegal in c#

```
Action<Mammal> m2 = (Animal a) => { };
```

But the following works fine.

```
Action<Mamal> m2 = MethodThatTakesAnimal;
```

MethodThatTakesAnimal has the following signature

```
public static void MethodThatTakesAnimal(Animal animal) { }
```